# How to get existing environment variable, change the value of it and display it after change with CMD command?

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

So, after discussing with Berend, I figured out that I need to explain myself better and that is what I'm going to do.
So, my mission is to write a windows batch script that will:

1. **Display**(print to screen) the value of anyone from the environment variables I have(but maybe I need to check if it exists, and if not I need to create one? I'm not sure)
   1.1 If I need to check if the variable exists, there is any if or for loop that I can do to check it?
   If not, I think that I'll just create new environment variable and work with it.
2. I need to update the value of the previous variable I just printed.
3. Display the value of the current variable **After** the update I just did in step 2.

I hope now it's more clear than before and I'll be glad for any help.

Comment: Just get rid of the quotes and reference existing variables as `%varname%`, e.g. `set /a a=10` or `set /a b=%a%+10`

Comment: but it still will create a new variable and I don't want it to do this. I want to change existing environment variable

Comment: That's unfortunately the way things work in the windows command prompt. For instance, you can't just echo the result of a calculation. `echo %a%+10` will display literally `10+10`

Comment: You can however do `set /a a=%a%+10` which will overwrite the variable `a`

Comment: I know, I think im not very clear so I'll try again.
I need to get an existing variable from environment variables (such as PATH directory or something).
After I get it, I need to display it, change(or like in the GUI - Edit) the path directory for something else and then display it with the new value -> new directory.

Comment: You mean, add an extra directory to PATH? Like `set PATH=C:\My\AdditionalDir;%PATH%` ?

Comment: No. 
I mean to change existing path directory for another directory. Edit the current one with another value.
I hope now it more clear

Comment: For example I've got this C:\My\AdditionalDir in my path, so I need to display it like this, Change the value for something new (like C:\My\AdditionalNewDirectory) and then display it again with the new value

Comment: I think I understand now. It can help if you edit your question and add specific examples  that show what exactly you want to change. For instance: PATH is initially THIS, and should be changed to THAT.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment I understand that you want to change one directory in the PATH variable.

For instance, if PATH is `C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\MyFolder` it needs to be changed to `C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\MyOtherFolder`

You can do that like this:

```
echo %PATH%
set PATH=%PATH:MyFolder=MyOtherFolder%
echo %PATH%
```

The syntax is `%VARIABLE:SEARCH=REPLACE%`

Comment: This would only temporarily change the %path% variable, to change it permanently after you close the batch you would have to use setx instead of set...

Comment: @RicardoBohner Of course, but there is no mention of making a permanent change in the question.

Comment: No, I dont need it permanent, only for the command running.
But I want to understand something.
First, if the user have many things inside Path, how can he recognize the change?
Second, there is any directory that everyone has?
Third, I really start to think to add a new path directory, print it for user and then change it.

Comment: To be more clear, when I make the echo %PATH%, how can i display a specific directory without showing all the paths I've got there?

Comment: You can use echo %path% to see the content of %paht% but if you actually change the value of the path variable you would have close the command window and open another one to see the changes. I think everyone has the c:\windows\system32 there are a couple of pahts that are there as soon as you install windows...

Comment: know that, but all the issue here is that I need in one shot print before change and print after the change. 
cmd command in batch script

Comment: That's easy you can save the output of the echo %path% to a text file and then use type with find comand to find what you want..

Comment: Thats something I haven't learned.
mmmm... I need to do echo %path% > path.txt, and then what I need to do?

Comment: @RicardoBohner Saving path to a file and then FIND won't work because everything is on a single line. There's a trick to split the path with newlines somewhere on this site, but I can't seem to find it right now.

Comment: @Berend so the only way to do what i need is this? :
```@echo off
echo %path%
set path=%path:c:\Windows=c:\Change%
echo %path%
pause```

Comment: @maoraverbuch That will change every occurence of C:\Windows to C:\Change, so if that is what you need, yes.

Comment: The trick is echo %path:;=&echo.%

Comment: I want to change something that everyone has, cause I've got C but someone else could have D or F or G . So i really start to think that i need to create new path, echo it, change it and echo it again with the new change.
And how should i do this?

Comment: @maoraverbuch I have the feeling we're kind of drifting away from your original question. I would recommend you first modify your question, or ask a new one, and make sure it contains a clear explanation of what exactly you want to do, and if possible with real-life examples.

Comment: @berend I dont want to spam here so in 30 minutes something like that, if Ill be allowed Ill edit the post and tag you again to let you know. Ill try to do this very clear now

Comment: @Berend just edited the post, will glad if you will move on it and try to help me again.

Comment: @maor averbuch have you checked my answer?

Comment: @RicardoBohner yes, also answer there. Hope you can see.
BTW, I tried this script but it won't work for me.. I changed the directories for something I have, but still nothing

Comment: But did you look at the changes inside the batch with echo %path% or outside of it?

Comment: @Berend Will glad for your help mate

Answer (score 0):

To check if a variable exist it is very simple:

```
IF Defined SomeVariable (Echo The Variable Exists) else (echo The Variable does not Exist)
```

To check if a variable has an empty value:

```
if "%SomeVariable%"=="" (Echo the Variable is Empty) else (echo The Variable is not Empty)
```

To see if a simple variable (one entry variable) has a specific value and if not change it to what you want:

```
if not "%SomeVariable%"=="ValueIWant" Setx SomeVariable "ValueIWant"
```

Some as above but no permanent change:

```
if not "%SomeVariable%"=="ValueIWant" Set SomeVariable=ValueIWant
```

To change the user or system %path% variable it is a little more complicated because this variable can have several entries separated by semi-column, here is an example of a batch that changes de user %path% variable to a new value:

what you have to do is change the the lines in:

set OldEntry=

set NewEntry=

I added a lot comments in the batch so you know what is going on.

Here in this video I show it in action  [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMV3FMHSuDA)

Code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: The OldEntry is the Entry that is already in your user %path% and the NewEntry is the New entry that is going to substitute OldEntry

set OldEntry=C:\Program Files\CLI\Speedtest
set NewEntry=C:\Mybanana

:: Saves current User %Path% in UserPath variable:
For /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query "HKCU\Environment" /v "Path"') do set "UserPath=%%b"
echo.

:: check if OldEntry exists in user %path% and if yes substitute OldEntry by NewEntry:
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"echo %UserPath:;=&echo.%"') do if /i "%%a"=="%OldEntry%" (
                                                                                     set "NewUserPath=!UserPath:%OldEntry%=%NewEntry%!"
                                                                                     setx Path "!NewUserPath!" 1> nul 2> nul
                                                                                    )

:: IF Variable NewUserPath does not exist that means there is no OldEntry in the current path and thus gives error:
IF not Defined NewUserPath goto :ErrorNotFound

:: IF success change was made a new window opens showing current and old Path...
For /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query "HKCU\Environment" /v "Path"') do set "NewUserPath=%%b"
start "" "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /c "(
                                          echo Old user %%path%%:
                                          echo.
                                          echo %UserPath:;=&echo.%
                                          echo.
                                          echo.
                                          echo Current user %%path%%:
                                          echo.                                          
                                          echo %NewUserPath:;=&echo.%
                                          echo.
                                          echo.
                                          echo OldEntry = "%OldEntry%"
                                          echo NewEntry = "%NewEntry%"
                                          echo.
                                          pause
                                         )"
exit

:ErrorNotFound
echo The Entry "%OldEntry%" was not found in the user %%path%%^^!
echo.
pause
exit
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment.
For your question - I guess it should not be permanent, something to do in script for the current moment - but after I exit from the script everything will be like before.
And for the setx, if I'm creating new variable so I think I should open new window, no? Im not sure...

About your code, I never meet this type of IF and so, can you explain me please what you did here?
You created 2 variables, OldPath that you use in the if, and you check if there is variable called OldPath so change it to NewPath?

Comment: I check if the path %OldPath% exist in %path% if yes exchange it with %NewPath% inside %path%. But the changes are only temporary until you close the batch. If you would like to create a new variable or change a existing one permanently you would have to use setx.

Comment: I think I want to edit an existing variable value, and like i saw(I've tried this script) it won't work.
What should I do?
if i use setx, than that's meaning that i need to exit from the script and re-enter, right?
so, the other option I've got it create local variable(like i did before) and change it non permanently - like this?
```@echo off
set /a "a=10"
echo %a%
set /a "b=a+10"
echo %b% 
pause```

Comment: What %path% variable do you actually want to change because there is a user path and a system path variable. To change the user path permanently it would be: setx path "NewValue". For the system path: setx path "NewValue" /M

Comment: I dont have something specific. I tell you exactly what I need to do is the 3 steps I wrote in the main post.
1 - show the value of any environment variable(one that i choose **that exist**)
2 - update the variable value from before
3 - show the new value of the variable I just updated.

I hope its more clear now.

Comment: Can you confirm in which of the %path% variables you want to do the change cause there is a user %path% and a system %path%: https://i.imgur.com/RCX1TEk.jpg

Comment: There's nothing specific, I can do it in user path and also in system path.
But I think the most important thing is to check if there is variable like this (that ill check)

Comment: Please check updated answer...

Comment: First of all, I really want to say THANK YOU! it's so amazing that you were film a video like this, I really appreciate it.
Secondly, that really good job what you did there and I want to ask - How can i do the change only for the script running? I mean, that it won't change it really in the environment variables?
Third thing is, can you do the same, just now create a variable into environment variables with a numeric value, echo it, change the value of it and echo it again?
Because I'm nut sure how to do it.

Comment: one more question. I tried this code (after I added the C:\Program Files\CLI\Speedtest to my environment variables path) and when the code is running it says that i was changed, but when I go into the user path variables - I don't see the MyBanana there - But the Speedtest was deleted. why?

Comment: Don't know, what Operating System do you use?I tested it in Windows 10 and Windows 7. May be typo in the batch or the the UI variables part. To make the changes temporarily only you use set Path=SomeValue instead of setx Path "SomeValue"

Comment: I using Windows 10 also, just don't really know why it was deleting the Speedtest value and not changed it to Banana.

Answer (score 0):

To add or change a number in a variable:

```
@echo off

:: Create a variable with a value of 5
set Number=5
echo Step 01: Number: %Number%
echo.

:: Change the value form 5 to 7
set Number=7
echo Step 02: Number: %Number%
echo.

:: Using matematical operations to add 3 to the current value of the variable %Number%
set /a Number=%Number% + 3
echo Step 03: Number: %Number%
echo.

:: Add the value of Number to another variable:
set SomeVariable=%Number%
echo Step 04: SomeVariable: %SomeVariable%
echo.
pause
```

Comment: I saw what you did with the set here (without setx) so I want to understand. If I do setx, I cant change it until I restart the batch script because it makes a new variable? But if I do set it only creates non premenant variable that the user will cant see after the script?

Comment: set is only valid while you run the batch and setx is permanent. If you use setx you can change it whenever you want but you can only use the variable created with setx in the next command prompt you open.

Comment: So, to my understanding, if I want to change in the current command prompt, I can use only the set? And one more thing, what about the above problem with the Speedtest that was deleted for me? I want to desolve this problem